# How can I get type of column in postgresql trigger function

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I want to get type of column from postgresql trigger function.

This query returns type of items:

```
Select pg_typeof(shape) from sde.my_points;
```

And this query returns type of geometry:

```
Select  GeometryType(shape) from sde.my_points;
```

I want to use this parts in postgresql trigger function:

```
 CREATE FUNCTION point_xy() RETURNS trigger AS $point_xy$
        BEGIN
                IF (SELECT pg_typeof(NEW.shape)) = ('geometry')
                   AND  GeometryType(NEW.shape) = ('POINT')
                THEN
                        NEW.x = st_x(NEW.shape);
                        NEW.y = st_y(NEW.shape);
                END IF;
            END IF;

            RETURN NEW;
        END
        $point_xy$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

This function gives error, in this line `(SELECT pg_typeof(NEW.shape))`.

> ERROR: invalid input syntax for type oid: "geometry"
>
> QUERY: SELECT (SELECT pg_typeof(NEW.shape)) = ('geometry')
>                                   AND  GeometryType(NEW.shape) = ('POINT')
>
> CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function point_xy() line 7

How can I use in function?

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: updated error code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pg_typeof()` returns a [`regtype`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-oid.html#DATATYPE-OID-TABLE) value, but the associated `=` operator can compare *any* kind of OIDs, so the value on the other side could be a type, a table, a function... The string `'geometry'` can't be automatically interpreted as a type name, so you'll need to cast it yourself. Try:

```
pg_typeof(NEW.shape) = 'geometry'::regtype
```

Comment: By the way, no need for the `SELECT`, just `IF pg_typeof(NEW.shape)='geometry'::regtype AND GeometryType(NEW.shape)='POINT' THEN ...`